# Image view with textviews in the linearlayout android

Tags: android, android-layout

Am new to android UI designing.I want to implement the view (like in the image) into the specified linear layout. please help to sort me out.

```
<Linear Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<include
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/header" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

  ?????????????????????????????

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/dash_progress"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/account_progress" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true" >
</ListView>
```

This the desired view i need

[image]

Comment: use main linear layout (horizontal )inside that put your image view after image view use another linear layout (vertical) put the views you need inside this liner layout use width for first image view if necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="100dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:text="Large Text"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:text="Button" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I need button along with textView1 as in the image. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/common_signin_btn_icon_dark" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_forward" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_plusone_medium_off_client" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Opthalmologist"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="UK" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Check this or you can do this with [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) simply

Answer (score 0):

You need a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).
It is the best way to position your components this way.